# Как выровнять текст в ровный столбик в левой колонке в таблице?

Tags: css

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 3px solid #c2c2c2; border-collapse: collapse;">
<caption style="padding: 5px;">"Personal <b><?php echo $name; ?></b> Cabine"</caption>
<tr> <td width="200">Имя</td><td align="left">name              </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Возвраст     </td><td align="left">age                </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Страна       </td><td align="left">Ukraine           </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>nickname     </td><td align="left">mynickname          </td> </tr>
</table>
```

возможно ли это сделать только средствами css, не вставляя ничего внутрь td?

[jsfiddle.net/example](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/Ey6rd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, чтоб текст колонки оставался по середине, но в то же время края строк были на одном уровне, то только одними средствами CSS и без использования каких-либо дополнительных элементов - не получится.

Ну, разве что [таким способом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Ey6rd/1/), который **не** рекомендую.

Comment: ну я так и сделал, только у меня от правого края отступилось, а вот интересно почему не рекомендуете, подводные камни?

Comment: Если у вас в колонке одно-два слова, то может еще терпимо, но напишите слов десять и увидите разницу. Кстати, как еще один не очень хороший вариант - использовать padding-left. Но тоже на глазок примерять будете.

Answer (score 0):

Замени  text-indent: 80px; - на padding-left

и убери first-child ( толку вообще их тут использовать ? )

Comment: Во-первых, по поводу padding-left - я писал раньше. Во-вторых, читайте вопрос: "... столбик в левой колонке ...", поэтому first-child, я использовал, дабы отфильтровать именно эту колонку. И в-третьих, 

> и убери first-child ...

Без приказного тона как-то можно?

Comment: тут стоит вопрос - о левой колонке, так как автор в правой колонке уже выровнял текст сам. Я же написал как сделать эту таблицу более однообразной
(если стоял вопрос ЧИСТО о левой колонке - то тут твой способ подойдет -> но я сомневаюсь что таблица должна иметь разные CSS для каждой колонки )

Answer (score 0):

[А так не вариант?](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/Ey6rd/embedded/result/)